# Youtube API v3 search for videos, retrieve title and url

Tags: java, android, api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can you search for youtube-movies and get the id/url and the title from it? It's to add them to a BaseAdapter-class in an Android Application.

In the second version of the API, it was possible: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos

Answer (score 14):

You need to do [search->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) and get ids, then plug in those ids into [videos->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to retrieve details.

I suggest you to try [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list) to understand those functionalities. They are inline with documents too.

[YouTube Direct Lite](https://github.com/youtube/ytd-android) project is a good one to get you started. Definitely read [README](https://github.com/youtube/ytd-android/blob/master/README.md) before starting.

Comment: the v3 seems extremely restrictive compared to the v2… To get full video infos, you need to be authenticated; did I read it right ?!!!

Comment: You can get basic videodetails without authenticating. Only filedetails, recordingdetails etc would need authentication.

Comment: I ended on others questions you replied to; some people arguing that likes, duration, views, etc... (if i remember the ones you get in a "statistics" call) should be defaults — in my opinion too

Comment: or there should be the possibility to chain api calls on googles server: search.list to videos.list