# How to get URL of a video using youtube API v3 using Java

Tags: list, url, search, video, youtube

I'm using Youtube API v3 to search videos by keyword. I'm currently using this code:

```
    YouTube youtube;
youtube = new YouTube.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
}}).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();
// query term.
String keyword = request.getParameter("keyword");

// api key
String apiKey = "my-api-key";

// Define the API request for retrieving search results.
 YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

// Set your developer key from the Google Cloud Console for
// non-authenticated requests. See:
// https://cloud.google.com/console
lstVideos.setKey(apiKey);
search.setKey(apiKey);
search.setQ(keyword);

// To increase efficiency, only retrieve the fields that the
// application uses.
search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
search.setMaxResults((long)10);
// Call the API and print results.
SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
Iterator<SearchResult> itsearch = searchResultList.iterator();
```

This works fine for me to get some data such as (id, thumbnail, etc). This code is available on [Youtube v3 API examples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#examples).

I saw a previous question on stackoverflow ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746449/youtube-api-v3-search-for-videos-retrieve-title-and-url)) that is basically the same but.. I can't figure out how to get this data. I can't see any Java example and I'm very lost.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but for anyone else that lands here from Googleland, here's an answer.

```
SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
ResourceId rId = singleVideo.getId();
```

Just tack rId.getVideoId() onto youtube.com/watch?v= and you have the url.

```
String url = "youtube.com/watch?v=" + rId.getVideoId();
```

Comment: @Have No Display Name: Thanks for the edit. It's hard to use the code feature on a tablet. :)

Comment: @Mark:- It happens:-)